# How/Where does JavaScript detect the default locale?

Tags: javascript, locale

Today, the 11th of September, 2017, JavaScript's `toLocaleDateString()` method is outputting `9/11/2017` for me. But I am in the UK, so the formatting is wrong in this case. The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) tell me that this method returns "a formatted string in the default locale".

So, where/how is JavaScript detecting my default locale? Where is this set, or what does it depend on, and (how) can I change it?

Edited to add: I'm using Firefox 55.0.3 on Windows 10 if that makes any difference.

Comment: It is implementation dependent: runtime should specify some locale as the "current", but the logic behind detection and so on is not standardised.

Comment: it's generally based on what your OS is set to....

Comment: does `navigator.language` result in `en-GB` ?

Comment: @Slai console.logging `navigator.language` gives me `en-US`. I wonder if it's because I installed the English (US) version of Firefox. Actually, I can't remember if I did, but I may well have.

Comment: then maybe check in the browser settings for something like preferred language

Comment: I set `en-gb` as my preferred language in the Firefox Content options (it had been set to `en-us`), but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Did you try restarting the browser?

Comment: I have the same thing, and `navigator.language` returns "en-GB"... I'm also running Firefox 55.03, on Linux...

Comment: Even with Chrome set to a non-US locale, and my OS environment set to a non-US locale, Chrome still formats dates as M/d/y

Answer (score 6):

I would just like to answer this in 2023 for anyone struggling with exactly the issue of the original post: where `Date` gets its default locale. Most Google results will land you on `navigator.languages`, but my machine was definitely not using those values. Here's what I saw on my console:

```js
new Date().toDateString()
// 'Fri Aug 04 2023'
navigator.languages
// (2) ['en-US', 'en']
new Date().toLocaleDateString()
// '04/08/2023'
new Date().toLocaleDateString(navigator.languages[0])
// '8/4/2023'
```

Though my languages are US-only, my machine region is set to Ireland, and  `toLocaleDateString` was reading that somehow and formatting the date in the Irish style, DD/MM/YYYY, as opposed to the US style, MM/DD/YYYY. After 30+ minutes of searches and drudging through lacking documentation, I finally found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57666095/2141290), which led me to my answer.

At least in Chrome on MacOS, the `Date` object sources its locale from `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale`, which was not documented anywhere that I could find. Hopefully this can save someone the frustration that I just went through.

Answer (score 5):

I checked JavaScript date and time formatting in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on my Windows 10 PC, with interesting results. My language tag should be "en-NZ', and I thought the locale behavior would follow accordingly.

Of the three browsers, only Edge had picked up the correct language tag by default, presumably from the OS, while Chrome and Firefox both defaulted to en-US. Edge also defaults to using the correct locale settings.

It seems I can influence the locale in Chrome by changing language in Advanced Settings to en-NZ, but the default locale behavior I get is as for en-GB. Firefox doesn't seem to care what my preferred language is for locale behavior, which depends only on the language "used to display menus, messages, and notifications from Firefox". The only English language options for that are US, Canada, or UK.

In Chrome and Firefox the only way to ensure the correct locale behavior seems to be to explicitly specify it in the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize shortly, detecting the current locale is implementation dependent and may differ from environment to environment. Your default language may also depend on the installer you've used to install your browser.

The not so short version:

Following the ECMAScript spec, [conforming browsers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-conformance) (and other environments, such as Node.js) should [implement localization](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring) following the [ECMAScript Internationalization API (ECMA-402)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/4.0/index.html), which only outlines the following for [getting the default locale](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/4.0/index.html#sec-defaultlocale):

> The DefaultLocale abstract operation returns a String value representing the *[...]* language tag for the host environment’s current locale.

This means that getting the default locale is implementation dependent and can differ from browser to browser. This is intentional, as it allows browser vendors to keep their current, differing implementations to stay conforming without much fuss.

While it's true that it would be nice to have this standardized as well, it's more beneficial to get **everyone** on board for a broad spec first and then work out the little kinks later.

Most modern browsers allow you to change your current default locale in their preferences (Chrome shown):

[image: Sample settings interface]

Comment: but then why is my browser supplying an incorrect locale? I would have expected the browser to take the locale from the operating system. I wonder if this would be fixed if I installed the "English (British)" localized version of Firefox [from here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/).

Comment: @osullic Most browsers allow you to change your current default language in the settings, I've made an edit to add that point.

Comment: Even with my OS set to a non-US english and the browser language set to a non-US locale, Chrome still formats all dates in US by default :-(

Answer (score -3):

You can pass locale as parameter. See the example below:

```
  var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
```

Comment: Apparently that's not (yet) fully supported, and doesn't answer the question; it's just a workaround.

Comment: Combining it with ```navigator.language``` seems to work okay, though I haven't tested it thoroughly. E.g: ```var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString(navigator.language)```

Comment: @JoLoCo—of course you're assuming that 1. the system has been set to the user's preferred language 2. the implementation supports that language 3. the user actually expects to see the format produced by those settings. Add to that the programmer has no idea what *toLocaleString* will produce for a particular user and that different implementations may produce different results and you start to get some idea of how flawed the concept of *toLocaleString* is.

Comment: @RobG Yes there are some assumptions being made! That the user's browser may have undesired settings is out of our control, of course it's nice to also provide a fall-back and a way to set the locale manually. But for me, in a real-world web app, this solution has been working well so far. There may be edge cases, but so far it seems that the correct date format is shown and the users are happy with the result.

Comment: @JoLoCo—it's exactly because settings are out of your control that you should make every attempt to avoid issues that may cause. For trivial applications, *toLocaleString* is probably sufficient (e.g. page header or footer), but where it matters (e.g. bookings and appointments), there's no substitute for specifying an unambiguous format.

Comment: @RobG Right y'are then.