# JavaScript's standard API to get the runtime's default locale?

Tags: javascript, locale, default-value

In order to determine the current locale I found different approaches:

1. Being in the browser, most people suggest looking at the HTTP headers (`Accept-Language`)
2. Some people suggest consulting `navigator.language`
3. Being in the backend (Node.js) and apart of HTTP, it is suggested to consult the (system dependent) `process.env`

On the other side, the ECMAScript Internationalization API defines the `locales` argument to each of the `Intl` constructors as optional:

> If the `locales` argument is not provided or is undefined, the runtime's
> default locale is used.

So, it seems as if there should be a browser-independent and OS independent way to get "the runtime's default locale".

Is there a more straight forward way to get the runtime's default locale than

```
new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale
```

?

---

The question [How/Where does JavaScript detect the default locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146573/how-where-does-javascript-detect-the-default-locale) is different as it asks for the *implementation* of detecting the default locale (in a browser host). In contrast to that, my question is not about implementation but about the existence of a standard API.

Comment: "*the runtime's default locale*" would be browser dependent, as it would fallback to the browser's implementation of the Internationalization API. (The browser does not require the ECMAScript standard when working with internal settings, such as the browser's locale)

Comment: Also note that the Node locale will give you the locale of the server, not the client's browser.

Comment: @JDB Your comments are absolutely clear but don't relate to my question. Especially, code running in Node.js doesn't need to be involved in HTTP communication at all, therefore no browser involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How/Where does JavaScript detect the default locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146573/how-where-does-javascript-detect-the-default-locale)

Comment: The quote in the highest voted answer means that there isn't a platform independent way to get the default locale as it is an abstract operation.

Comment: @zero298 Thx for the hint. The quote from the ECMAScript Internationalization API spec is correct but actually does *not* state or mean that there isn't a standard API function for that (while the implementation may be or is platform dependent). The spec even defines a "abstract operation" `DefaultLocale()` but unfortunately does not offer an API function for that. So, we know that at least the ECMAScript Intern. API does not offer such a function. But maybe another one? - That's the question!

Comment: Where does this quote come from? The specs only speak of "host", never of *runtime*, and the host **is the browser** when js is executed in a browser. This question doesn't make sense, you can't have a "browser independent" way to get the browser's set locale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of a more straight-forward approach, but as you have already pointed out,

1. `new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` is a solution
2. `DefaultLocale` is an abstract operation, which might or might not be implemented in the future.

Hence, I would argue for polyfilling this `function` as:

```
if (typeof DefaultLocale === "undefined") {
    function DefaultLocale() {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
    }
}
```

So, your code will reasonably assume the existence and call this `function`. In some point in the future, when this `function` is implemented in a standard manner, you will be able to clean up by removing the chunk from above.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this as a choice, doesn't seem to be much better than the shim from Lajos because I guess one would need to have a request and to interpret the q (see the MDN excerpt below).

If you can get hold of a request's headers, most browsers inject:

```
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.9,ro;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7
```

From MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language :

> - A language tag (which is sometimes referred to as a "locale identifier"). This consists of a 2-3 letter base language tag
>   representing the language, optionally followed by additional subtags
>   separated by '-'. The most common extra information is the country or
>   region variant (like 'en-US' or 'fr-CA') or the type of alphabet to
>   use (like 'sr-Latn'). Other variants like the type of orthography
>   ('de-DE-1996') are usually not used in the context of this header.
> - Any language; '*' is used as a wildcard.
> - ;q= (q-factor weighting) Any value placed in an order of preference expressed using a relative quality value called weight.

The way I understand it, the highest weight (q-value) should be prefered, if available