# Browser default locale - Intl.DateTimeFormat vs navigator.language

Tags: javascript, browser, localization, locale

When coding a website and formatting a date, I want to use the locale that the user has set in their browser.

So for example, if a user has customised their `chrome://settings/languages` setting in Chrome to something non-default, that's the value I want to use.

However, when I run the code below in the console of such a browser, I get two different values.

```
 [window.navigator.language, new Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale]
// Array [ "en-AU", "en-US" ]
```

`navigator.language` gives me the expected value, but `new Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` does not.

MDN for both items seems (to me) to indicate that they should be returning the same value:

- [NavigatorLanguage.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language)

  > returns a string representing the preferred language of the user
- [Intl.DateTimeFormat locale parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat#Parameters)

  > To use the browser's default locale, omit this argument or pass undefined.

Should both of these calls be returning the locale the user configured in their browser settings?

Answer (score 12):

I'm using macOS and found that Chrome's `navigator.languages` reflects the browser language setting while `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` reflects the OS language setting. Don't know if this is also the case in other OSs.

Comment: My MacBook is language `en-US`, but my region is set to `de` and my time formatting is German as well, yet `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` will return `en-US` when it should return `en-DE`, actually.

Answer (score 8):

I also saw this and have done a bit of testing.

### Chrome

On Windows Chrome 85 appears offers two different ways to set the language in it's configuration:

1. A list of languages in order of preference. This appears to drive `navigator.languages`.
2. A language which is used to "display the Google Chrome UI". This appears to drive `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale`.

For example when I have this set:
[image: Google Chrome language settings]

I get this:

```
navigator.languages                            : en-US, en-GB, en
navigator.language                             : en-US
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale : en-GB
```

Note that on Mac with Chrome 85 there did not appear to be these two separate settings, but just the ability to set an order of languages (not an option for setting the language to "display the Google Chrome UI").

### Node

In Node I found that the value of `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` was driven by the language settings of my operating system. Note I only tested this on Windows, but I assume the same is true elsewhere.

### Side note on time zone

I saw that for `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` both Chrome and Node use the OS setting for the time zone (also only tested on Windows). Chrome does not appear to have its own setting for time zone in its settings so I guess just uses the OS configuration.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working that way for me (on Windows). The first language in my Chrome Languages list is also listed as "This language is used to display the Google Chrome UI", but it's my 2nd language that is returned by `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale`.

Comment: Hmm interesting, in that case I'm not sure, I only tried some local testing and am not sure how it works under the hood.