# Does Intl.DateTimeFormat()'s `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` use the format defined in the OS preferences?

Tags: javascript, date, internationalization

In the past I've always said it's not possible to display the date/time in the format as defined by the user in their OS preferences. For example, I may have EN-US as my language/region but prefer to use a 24-hour time format. Or, I may have changed the `short` date format from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yy`.

Has this changed now that `Intl.DateTimeFormat` can use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` values? Note: these options are not supported in all browsers at the time of writing this.

The values for `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` are:

- `full`
- `long`
- `medium`
- `short`

These predefined formats (`full`, `long`, etc) can be defined by the user in their system preferences, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK19q.jpg).

Do the values of `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` use the same format as defined in the OS preferences for the values of `full`, `long`, etc?

Here's an example. In the snippet below I have used `toLocaleString` to display the current date/time. For the options I have passed `dateStyle: 'long'` and `timeStyle: 'long'`. Will this use the same format as defined in my OS preferences even if I change the 'long' format to a custom format?

```js
const event = new Date();
console.log(event.toLocaleString(undefined, { dateStyle: 'long', timeStyle: 'long', timeZone: 'UTC' }));
```

Comment: "*An ECMAScript implementation that includes the ECMA-402 Internationalization API must implement the Date.prototype.toLocaleString method as specified in the [ECMA-402 specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/6.0/index.html#Title).*"

Answer (score 1):

**Sometimes.**

dateStyle and timeStyle addition is a stage 3 [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-datetime-style), so they are not yet fully finalized. That said, the question is not really about these specific options, but rather about how the engine decides to retrieve the default locale settings and whether it includes the customizations the user has made.

The ECMAscript specification describes the default locale as implementation-specific, so it’s up to the engine to make this decision. See more details in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146784/1050610).

It makes a lot of good sense to use the user’s OS preferences, and Edge does so. However, Chrome and Firefox allow the user to choose the browser language independently, and this causes inconsistencies with how the rest of the application behaves. See a more thorough discussion in [Firefox bug 1366136](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1366134).

So to summarize, the answer is dateStyle and timeStyle will sometimes take user’s OS preferences into account, and sometimes they will not.

Comment: "*The ECMAscript specification describes the default locale as implementation-specific*". Where? ECMA-402 defines a [default locale](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/6.0/index.html#sec-defaultlocale) represented by a BCP47 language tag (which highlights the confusion caused by representing locations with a languate).

Comment: The default locale must be a language tag, but the specification does not prescribe how to choose it. The app may choose the locale the user has set in its settings, or retrieve the OS-wide settings. Both will still be language tags.

Comment: That wasn't my question, which was: where does ECMAScript specify a default locale for *toLocaleString*? It's only mentioned in regard to [*localeCompare*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-string.prototype.localecompare), and only where ECMA-402 is not supported.

Comment: [toLocaleString in step 4](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/4.0/index.html#sup-date.prototype.tolocalestring) refers to %DateTimeFormat%, then InitializeDateTimeFormat, then in step 9 ResolveLocale, then in step 2 LookupMatcher, and finally, in step 8, DefaultLocale. Forgive me if I still misunderstand your question.